# Buttons placed below UIscrollview get disabled or not works during scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

I placed the buttons below scroll view and enable vertical scrolling.After scrolling,the buttons are visible,If I click buttons doesn’t work.

1.This Image shows the "story Board" which contains "table view" inside "scroll view" and the "buttons" placed below "scroll view" "Buttons" shown in "blue colour".

scroll view specification in story board (0,83,568,237)

Table view specification in story board  (2,4,564,229)

[image]

2.This Image shows the "view" without scrolling.

[image]

3.This Image represents the "vertical scrolling" with towards "up" direction.

My Piece of code For "vertical Scrolling"

```
[_scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[_scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(_scroller.bounds.size.width, _scroller.bounds.size.height*3)];
```

My piece of code for displaying "scrollview" ,"tableview","Buttons" similarly in iPad and iPhone:

```
[_tblview setFrame:CGRectMake(0,80,self.view.frame.size.height,self.view.frame.size.width)];
[_scroller setFrame:CGRectMake(0,80,self.view.frame.size.height,self.view.frame.size.width)];
[_btnSave setFrame:CGRectMake(0,self.view.frame.size.width-50,50,25)];
[_btnSubmit setFrame:CGRectMake(55,self.view.frame.size.width-50,50,25)];
[_btnCancel setFrame:CGRectMake(110,self.view.frame.size.width-50,50,25)];
```

[image]

4.This Image represents the "vertical scrolling" towards down direction.It shows three "buttons" save,submit,cancel.after scrolling towards down,If I click any of these buttons.None of the action occurs.It's the issue.

[image]

What might be the issue.I have to alter the "buttons" CGRectmake or reduce the size of scroll view and table view or Modify the UI design with place the buttons on the top of scroll view.Please provide me some solution for me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes ....what might be the solution....

Comment: When you describe a view as 'below' or 'above' another you appear to be talking about the 'z' axis rather than the 'y' axis, more appropriate terms (if I understand you correctly) might be 'behind' and 'in front of'...  Views which are responding to touch events do not by default forward those touch events to views which are behind them.   Also, why are you nesting the tableView in a scrollView? Did you know that UITableView inherits from UIScrollView?

Comment: @Jef  please take a look at this screen shot. http://i.imgur.com/j3cyRja.png explanation about this screen shot. If I click add button rows get iterated.It's a table view,If I scroll table view it return backs to its original position.I can't edit the bottom rows.That's why I Implement scroll view idea.Table view scrolls and return to its original state.If i used scroll view,I can hold the particular row and edit.That's why I implement the scroll view.

Comment: @Jef do u take a look at that screen shot and comment.If you have any simple solution.Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

please check userInteractionEnabled

```
outerLayer.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```

Comment: here "outerlayer" denotes what "scroller" or  "buttons"

Comment: _scroller.userInteractionEnabled=YES;  bro I put this code inside viewdidload but nothing changes...

Answer (score 0):

```
[scrolViewFrames removeFromSuperview];
scrolViewFrames=nil;
scrolViewFrames= [[UIScrollView alloc]init];
scrolViewFrames.frame= CGRectMake(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT-60, SCREEN_WIDTH, 60);
scrolViewFrames.backgroundColor= BLACK_COLOR;
[self.view addSubview:scrolViewFrames];


NSArray *cropFrames= @[@"original",@"3.2",@"16.9",@"square",@"2.1",@"3.1",@"3.4",@"7.5",@"16.10"];
NSArray *cropFramesSelected= @[@"original_sel",@"3.2_sel",@"16.9_sel",@"square_sel",@"2.1_sel",@"3.1_sel",@"3.4_sel",@"7.5_sel",@"16.10_sel"];

float _x=15;
float _y=0;
float _width=50;
float _height=60;

for (int i=0; i<cropFrames.count; i++)
{

    UIButton *threeTwoRatioButton= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    threeTwoRatioButton.frame= CGRectMake(_x, _y, _width, _height);
    threeTwoRatioButton.backgroundColor= BLACK_COLOR;
    [threeTwoRatioButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeRatioButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [threeTwoRatioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[cropFrames objectAtIndex:i] ]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [threeTwoRatioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[cropFramesSelected objectAtIndex:i] ]forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    threeTwoRatioButton.tag=400+i;
    [scrolViewFrames addSubview:threeTwoRatioButton];

    if(i==0){

        threeTwoRatioButton.selected=YES;
    }

    _x=_x+ _width +15;

}

    scrolViewFrames.contentSize= CGSizeMake(_x, _height);

this is my working code
```

Comment: yes sir, try this if u not get any idea. its not tough